# Database file-level encryption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, encryption

We recently were given a client requirement to encrypt all their data while at rest.  They have agreed that encrypting the dbf, backup and trn files will suffice this need for them.  My question is, do I need to encrypt the ldf file also?  Is there any retrievable data in the ldf file that would require it to be encrypted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that is written to the database is in the LDF.

Depending on your Recovery model depends how long this data will be there for.

It could be until you next perform a logfile backup.

Either way, yes, you should consider it to have as much valuable information in it as your database itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly read a SQL Server log file. All you need is a log analyzer of which there are many available on the internet.

You can even build your own.

Cheers, John